# Plotting piecewise function using declare function

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, plot, pgfmath

I am trying to plot a piecewise defined function, but somehow I don't manage to get it right. See below.

[image: The function to be plotted above, the failed plot below.]

I use the following code

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[
declare function={
func(\x)=(\x >8/10) * (6/10* \x) +
 and(\x > 0.6,\x <= 0.8)* (6/9* \x )    + 
            (\x<=0.6) * (\x*6/8);
}
]
\begin{axis}[xmin=0,xmax=1,
              ymin=0,ymax=1,
              x dir=reverse]
\addplot[]{func(x)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

My understanding was that `and(cond,cond)` gives me 1 when both conditions hold and zero otherwise. Then, isn't the function I declared correct?
I see that the first part is correct. 
But I don't understand why it isn't followed by a jump as supposed. I also don't understand the kink at 0.4 instead of 0.6.

I expected a function that decreases (because I reversed the x axis) and has upward jumps at 0.8 and 0.6. What am I doing wrong?

I am having the same problem with

`\pgfmathdeclarefunction{func}{1}{%   \pgfmathparse{...`

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are not doing anything wrong. It's just that you are using the default sample number and the default domain. Adjusting them gives you the result.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[
declare function={func(\x)=(\x>0.8)*(0.6*\x)+and(\x>0.6,\x<=0.8)*(2/3*\x)+(\x<=0.6)*(\x*0.75);}
]
\begin{axis}[xmin=0,xmax=1,samples=351,domain=0:1,
              ymin=0,ymax=1,
              x dir=reverse]
\addplot[]{func(x)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

Comment: @Bayesian And you can use a ternary operator to declare your function if you want, like this `declare function={func(\x)=\x>.8?(6*\x/10):(\x>.6?(6*\x/9):(6*\x/8));}`