# How to graph piece wise function. f(x)={-x for -l<x≤0 & 0 otherwise}

Tags: diagrams, plot

```
f(x)={-x for -l<x≤0
          & 0 otherwise}
```

How to graph the above equation.
pls help.
also explain

Comment: If you have tried anything, please add the code.

Comment: f(x)={-x for -l<x≤0 
          & 0 otherwise}
thats my question.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UschNWVttUI

Comment: Google piece wise function pgfplots

Comment: @PauloCereda This is gold!

Comment: I was unable to update my ques as it waa showing error so i jus use randim words and posted it.
&
I wanna know how to graph my function

Comment: Rather than closing as unclear I would suggest flagging as low quality to have it deleted.

Comment: I simply want an answer on how to plot above function,thats it.!

Comment: Gentlemen, let us save this questions. `:)`

Comment: Its better to answer.

Comment: I see the problem with your post. It's allowed to use some HTML in questions, and HTML tags start with `<`. I guess the `<x` was interpreted as the start of a tag, but as it wasn't completed, it was discarded. Marking as code (select and hit Ctrl + K) helped things.

Comment: @Rahilgupta Please help us to help you. Did you have a look at http://tex.stackexchange.com/search?q=plot+piecewise for already existing examples? What have you already tried?

Comment: No example match this 1.

Comment: @Rahilgupta How about http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/261534/36296, this plots a function with 3 cases.

Comment: Well am a new user here.
How this site works,mean how generally 1 ask a question about.

Comment: Hi and [welcome to TeX.SX](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436). In its current form, your question might not receive many answers. Please take a look at the [How to Ask](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-ask)-page and try to improve your question according to the guidance found there. This may require you to show some effort on your part in terms of attempting a solution. If you have questions about what to do or if you don't quite understand what this means, please ask for clarification using the `add comment` function.

Comment: This should not be closed yet. Please wait at least 24 hours after asking the OP for improvements to the question before voting to close. Also, if you downvote, please don't forget to revert the vote after the question is improved.

Comment: @Rahilgupta You have by now received 7 high-quality answers to your poorly phrased question.  Please mark one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 14):

I suggest you use the `pgfplots` package.  Since your function has three intervals I split the plot in these three

```
 0  for x ≤ -l
-x  for -l < x ≤ 0
 0  for 0 < x
```

There is a discontinuity point at `x = -l`, so I drew a filled circle at `f(-l) = 0` and an empty circle at `f(-l) = l`.

Also, don't forget to [jksabn](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-ask) [a alkew](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) [klakjlre](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
    xlabel={$x$},ylabel={$f(x)$},
    xtick={-1,0},xticklabels={$-l$,$0$},
    ytick={0,1},yticklabels={$0$,$l$},
    no marks,
    ]
    \addplot[blue,domain=-2:-1] {0};
    \addplot[blue,domain=-1:0] {-x};
    \addplot[blue,domain=0:2] {0};
    \node[blue,draw,fill=blue ,circle,inner sep=1pt] at (axis cs:-1,0) {};
    \node[blue,draw,fill=white,circle,inner sep=1pt] at (axis cs:-1,1) {};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

> [image]

Answer (score 9):

Probably you like to draw single saw tooth ...

[image]

With help of TikZ it is easy:

```
\documentclass[border=3mm,tikz]{standalone}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[ ->]  (0,-0.1) node[below] {0} -- (0,2) node[below right] {$f(x)$};
\draw[<->]  (-3,0) node[below] {$-\infty\gets x$} -- 
            ( 3,0) node[below] {$x \to +\infty$};
\draw   (-0.1,1) node[left] {1} -- + (0.2,0);
\draw   (-1,0.1) -- + (0,-0.2) node[below] {$-1$};
%
\draw[very thick,red]   (-2.5,0) -- (-1,0)
                        (-1.0,1) -- (0,0)
                        ( 0.0,0) -- (2.5,0);
\draw[very thin,dashed,red] (-1,0) -- (-1,1);
\end{tikzpicture}            
\end{document}
```

Comment: There is a handy synonym for `\leftarrow` which is `\gets` (just as `\to` for `\rightarrow`)

Comment: Thank for editing my answer, it seems that new year is to young that I will be full operational :( ,

Comment: @HenriMenke, thank you for `\gets`, I will consider it.

Answer (score 7):

For the sake of quackiness, let us add a `gnuplot` hybrid solution! `:)`

```
% arara: pdflatex: { shell: yes }
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{gnuplottex}

\begin{document}

\begin{gnuplot}[terminal=pdf]
set key inside left top vertical Right noreverse enhanced autotitles box linetype -1 linewidth 1.000
f(x) = -1 < x && x <= 0 ? -x : 0
plot f(x)
\end{gnuplot}

\end{document}
```

The output:

[image: Quack]

Comment: Something's weird with gnuplot's choice of points for this plot: the line never gets to (-1, 1) or (0, 0).

Comment: @Mike: indeed, I will take a look later, I believe it's a matter of specifying the desired range. I don't even use `gnuplot` that much. `:)`

Comment: @PauloCereda Might also be related to the amount of sampled points, I'd guess. If yes, 'set sample 1000' should help. And why using the pdfterminal if there is the cairolatex or even tikz terminal? :p

Answer (score 5):

Here is a way with `pstricks`:

```
\documentclass[border=4pt, svgnames]{standalone}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\usepackage{pst-plot, pst-node}
\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf}

\begin{document}

\psset{unit=3cm, arrowinset=0.12, ticksize= -2pt 2pt, linejoin=1}
\begin{pspicture*}(-2.6,-1.1)(1.6,1.9)
    \psaxes[linecolor=LightSteelBlue, tickcolor=LightSteelBlue]{->}(0,0)(-2.6,-1.1)(1.6,1.9)[$x$, -135] [$y$,-135]%
    \uput[dl](0,0){0}
    \pnode(-2.6,0){A}\pnode{} \pnode(0,0.9pt){O} \pnode(1.55,0.9pt){B}\pnode(-1,0){C}\pnode(-1,1){D}
    \psline[linestyle=dashed, dash=4pt 4pt, linewidth=0.3pt](0,1)(D)(C)
    \psset{linecolor=IndianRed}
    {\psset{linewidth =1.2pt}
    \ncline[offset=0.9pt, dotsize=3pt, arrows=-*]{A}{C}\psline(D)(O)(B)}
    \psdot[dotstyle=o](D)
\end{pspicture*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Another way with [mfpic](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/mfpic?lang=en), a very efficient LaTeX interface to [MetaPost](https://www.tug.org/metapost.html):

```
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage[metapost]{mfpic}
\setlength{\mfpicunit}{1cm}
\opengraphsfile{\jobname}
\begin{document}
\begin{mfpic}[3]{-2.5}{1.5}{-0.5}{1.5}
   \doaxes{xy}
   \dashed\lines{(-1, 1), (0, 1)}
   \drawcolor{red}
   \dashed\lines{(-1, 0), (-1, 1)}
   \penwd{1bp}
   \lines{(\xmin, 0), (-1, 0)}
   \lines{(-1, 1), (0, 0), (\xmax-.04, 0)}
   \pointcolor{red}
   \point[4pt]{(-1, 0)}
   \pointfillfalse
   \point[4pt]{(-1, 1)}
   \tlpointsep{3bp}
   \tlabels{[tc](\xmax, 0){$x$} [cr](0, \ymax){$y$} [tr](0, 0){$O$}
     [tc](-1, 0){$-1$} [br](0, 1){$1$}}
\end{mfpic}
\closegraphsfile
\end{document}
```

To be compiled with LaTeX, then MetaPost, then LaTeX again. Result:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

With Asymptote.

```
settings.outformat="pdf";
import graph;

size(6cm,4cm,IgnoreAspect);

real l = 1;
real epsilon = 1e-16;

real f(real x) {
  if (-l < x && x <= 0)
    return -x;
  else
    return 0;
}

draw(graph(f, -2, -l-epsilon),blue);
draw(graph(f, -l+epsilon, 2),blue);
dot((-l,f(-l-epsilon)),blue);
dot((-l,f(-l+epsilon)),blue,UnFill);

ylimits(-0.2,1.2);

xaxis("$x$",BottomTop,LeftTicks);
yaxis("$y$",LeftRight,RightTicks);
```

> [image]

Answer (score 2):

A solution using `R`, embedded in the `LaTeX` source file, precompiled using `knitr`.

```
\documentclass[border=.25in]{standalone}
\begin{document}
<<echo=FALSE>>=
plot(NA,xlim=c(-2,2),ylim=c(-.2,1.2),xlab="x",ylab="y") 
curve(0*x, from=-2, to=-1, add=TRUE)
curve(-x, from=-1, to=0, add=TRUE)
curve(0*x, from=0, to=2, add=TRUE)
@
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: `0*x` is quite impressive. I would suggest using `lines(c(-2,-1), rep(0,2))` etc., `points` with `pch=16` to show inclusion/exclusion, and finally, set the `ylim=c(-0.05, 1.05)`. And probably `asp=1`, too.